# Iterating rows in MySQLi results array in PHP to store as new nested array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have to start by saying I am stil fairly new to PHP here. I'm slowly getting my head round the functions by RTFM... I'm using procedural style PHP with MYSQLi as I struggle with PDO at present.

The question below I have been stuck on a while & I fear if I keep changing and amending I am digging deeper into a hole rather than putting it out there for some hopeful assistance.

I have data from an EPOS system within a MySQL database. I have populated this data by a number of Curl handlers inside foreach loops in PHP as the EPOS system API requires different calls for each data piece e.g. transaction header, transaction items, tender, customers etc...

Now I have this data, I need to gather the parent:child elements in a multi-dimensioanl array & eventually once I have these arrays correct,  output data to a pipe delimited file for import into a 3rd party system. I was planning to run this PHP file to poll the database at a configured frequency via a windows scheduled task which I have several of already running succesfully in a production environment for other processes.

I hoped I could process this data in a similar way to the process I used for getting it and use nested foreach loops within PHP to populate an array that I can then ouput to file.

I can get the first array to populate with the transaction id's to create the primary key for getting parent records but I then seem to be struggling with unexpected results for the sub-query within a foreach loop.

I seem to be creating 12 empty arrays as the sub-query using the below, & am unsure of how I would need to go about adding child elements to these parent arrays as a multi-dimensional array?

The current code I have is as per below:

```
<?php
//Error Reporting in Browser - DEV ONLY.
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//get config & includes
include 'config.php';
include 'functions.php';

//Set runtime var of script
$rt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// connect to the mysql database
$link = $con;
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT TransactionId FROM epos_transactions WHERE Processed = 0";

$tranresult = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) >= "0") {
http_response_code(200);    
}
elseif (mysqli_affected_rows($link) == "-1") {
$err = mysqli_errno($link) . " : " . mysqli_error($link);
exceptions_logger($err);
}

$transac = $tranresult->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Loop each transactionID & Produce TH Records.
foreach($transac as $row)
{   
$TransactionId = $row['TransactionId'];

unset($sql);
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM EPOS.TH where Trans_ID = $TransactionId";

        $resulth = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) >= "0") {
        http_response_code(200);    
        }
        elseif (mysqli_affected_rows($link) == "-1") {
        $err = mysqli_errno($link) . " : " . mysqli_error($link);
        exceptions_logger($err);
        }

        $throw = $resulth->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}       
var_dump($throw); //Only returning one result instead of 12 outside of loop?
?>
```

The code above is selecting the ID's of transactions eligible for export & then trying to selct the data for the parent rows of an array which afterwards I will then need to select the child elements for each parent row and store them in an array also that can eventually be output to a file with each transaction listing it's parent & child items.

The file out process I will tackle later on but was really hoping for some tips on the loopoing process to help get a data set initially.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to update, I have the code similar to the above but have replac ed the SQL query now with a much smaller query as I have used a MySQL view instead due to calculated results being required.

Comment: It may be complex to get your head around by do try and get into Prepared Statements. you can use `MySQLi` if you dn't like `PDO`

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this one by some further research on here. Needed to set the array initially outside of the foreach loop which then allows results to be read outside of the loop once populated.